# Conda stopped installing packages

Tags: python, conda

After trying to install Caffe on my mac `10.12.6`, system-wide, which is a really hellish process, `conda` started behaving oddly.

I can activate my conda environments with `source activate env`, but no longer can install anything using `conda install`, nor does conda accept any other commands.

terminal just prompts back nothing.

I have `export PATH="/Users/xxx/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` on my `.bash_profile`

could anybody please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Can you provide some errors that you're seeing when you try to run the conda commands?

Comment: no errors, that's the problem. commands return nothing.

Comment: can you try: conda install --debug -v -v -v  and see what errors there are? Also try "which conda" and confirm if it's pointing to the correct version of conda?

Comment: `conda install --debug -v -v -v` returns nothing and `which conda` returns `/Users/xxx/anaconda/bin/conda`

Comment: What is your version of conda? Also, out of curiosity, what made this such a hellish process?

Comment: Cuda + OS + XCode gave me hell, or worse, via homebrew. oh, a mess of dependencies. when I tried to use conda, I realized it was broke after all my try and errors. now I ca'nt even check what my version of conda is

Comment: Do you have same symptoms as [outkast's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47040270/8379597)?