# Conda command fails silently

Tags: python, homebrew, caffe, conda

My anaconda is behaving oddly.

`conda list`, `conda debug`, `conda install`, all return **nothing**.

I have already reinstalled `anaconda2`, checked my path on `.profile`, and it's all there.

**1. `which -a conda`**

```
/Users/me/anaconda2/bin/conda
```

**2. `echo $PATH`**

```
/Users/me/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

**3. `~/.profile`:**

```
# added by Anaconda2 5.0.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/me/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

**4. `brew doctor`:**

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/curl-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/icu-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/libpng16-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/pcre-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/python-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/python2-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/python2.7-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/xslt-config
```

**EDIT**

so far I have been able to reuse anaconda installing it via `brew cask install anaconda`, because I was trying to get rid of eventual (and suspected) incompatibilities between `homebrew` and `anaconda`.

for that purpose I had to reset my path to:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:"$PATH"
```

and now anaconda works.

however, my canonical anaconda path at `export PATH="/Users/me/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` remains broken up to this point.

**EDIT2** Contents of `/Users/me/anaconda2/bin`:

```
total 488472
drwxr-xr-x  390 me  staff      13260 Nov  3 00:58 .
drwxr-xr-x   25 me  staff        850 Oct 31 04:07 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 me  staff       6148 Nov  3 00:57 .DS_Store
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff        536 Oct 18 15:30 .anaconda-navigator-post-link.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff        142 Oct 18 15:30 .anaconda-navigator-pre-unlink.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff        661 Sep 13 09:09 .dbus-post-link.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff        139 Sep 12 07:07 .python.app-post-link.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff         38 Sep 12 07:07 .python.app-pre-unlink.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff        276 Sep 21 19:01 .qt-post-link.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff        114 Sep 21 19:01 .qt-pre-unlink.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        118 Oct 31 03:41 2to3
drwxr-xr-x    3 me  staff        102 Oct 31 03:42 Assistant.app
drwxr-xr-x    3 me  staff        102 Oct 31 03:42 Designer.app
drwxr-xr-x    3 me  staff        102 Oct 31 03:42 Linguist.app
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       3802 Oct 17 16:29 activate
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        254 Oct 31 03:44 anaconda
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        255 Oct 31 03:44 anaconda-navigator
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:44 anaconda-project
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      12011 Oct 31 03:42 asadmin
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      26617 Oct 31 03:41 autopoint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        431 Oct 31 03:44 binstar
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:44 blaze-server
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        242 Oct 31 03:43 bokeh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1577 Oct 31 03:42 bundle_image
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     115756 Sep 20 09:05 bunzip2
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     115756 Sep 20 09:05 bzcat
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 bzcmp -> bzdiff
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       2128 Sep 20 09:05 bzdiff
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 bzegrep -> bzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 bzfgrep -> bzgrep
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       1677 Sep 20 09:05 bzgrep
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     115756 Sep 20 09:05 bzip2
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      18792 Sep 20 09:05 bzip2recover
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 bzless -> bzmore
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       1259 Sep 20 09:05 bzmore
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5166 Oct 31 03:41 c_rehash
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          3 Oct 31 03:41 captoinfo -> tic
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       3467 Oct 31 03:42 cfadmin
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        250 Oct 31 03:42 chardetect
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      32756 Sep 13 17:16 cjpeg
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       8700 Sep 11 20:39 clear
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        237 Oct 31 03:44 conda
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        254 Oct 31 03:44 conda-build
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        256 Oct 31 03:44 conda-convert
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        256 Oct 31 03:44 conda-develop
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        246 Oct 31 03:44 conda-env
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        254 Oct 31 03:44 conda-index
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        256 Oct 31 03:44 conda-inspect
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        260 Oct 31 03:44 conda-metapackage
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        255 Oct 31 03:44 conda-render
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        441 Oct 31 03:44 conda-server
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        257 Oct 31 03:44 conda-skeleton
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        245 Oct 31 03:42 conda-verify
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       3076 Oct 31 03:42 cq
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        567 Oct 31 03:43 createfontdatachunk.py
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     209708 Sep 20 10:57 curl
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5647 Oct 31 03:41 curl-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5068 Oct 31 03:42 cwutil
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:43 cygdb
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        270 Oct 31 03:43 cython
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        250 Oct 31 03:43 cythonize
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 dask-mpi
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        251 Oct 31 03:43 dask-remote
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        254 Oct 31 03:43 dask-scheduler
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 dask-ssh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        251 Oct 31 03:43 dask-submit
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        251 Oct 31 03:43 dask-worker
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      13952 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-cleanup-sockets
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     209744 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-daemon
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      23468 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-launch
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      25596 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-monitor
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      13632 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-run-session
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      25724 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-send
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      24692 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-test-tool
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      14400 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-update-activation-environment
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      13340 Oct 31 03:42 dbus-uuidgen
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       3040 Oct 17 16:29 deactivate
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      30828 Oct 31 03:41 derb
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      32036 Sep 13 17:16 djpeg
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      40036 Sep 15 00:06 dltest
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2156 Oct 31 03:42 dynamodb_dump
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       3526 Oct 31 03:42 dynamodb_load
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root           staff        259 Nov  2 00:14 easy_install
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        259 Nov  2 00:14 easy_install-2.7
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       9716 Oct 31 03:42 elbadmin
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1598 Oct 31 03:43 enhancer.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      38784 Oct 31 03:41 envsubst
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 epylint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2463 Oct 31 03:43 explode.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        783 Oct 31 03:42 f2py
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      23488 Sep 13 17:17 fax2ps
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      23464 Sep 13 17:17 fax2tiff
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1896 Oct 31 03:42 fetch_file
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        269 Oct 31 03:43 fits2bitmap
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        261 Oct 31 03:43 fitscheck
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        260 Oct 31 03:43 fitsdiff
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        262 Oct 31 03:43 fitsheader
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        260 Oct 31 03:43 fitsinfo
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       6004 Sep 21 18:59 fixqt4headers.pl
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        237 Oct 31 03:43 flask
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5184 Oct 31 03:41 freetype-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      63328 Oct 31 03:42 gdbus
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1533 Oct 31 03:42 gdbus-codegen
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      23204 Oct 31 03:41 genbrk
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      18312 Oct 31 03:41 gencfu
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      31932 Oct 31 03:41 gencnval
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      30036 Oct 31 03:41 gendict
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     156100 Oct 31 03:41 genrb
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      38500 Oct 31 03:41 gettext
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       4629 Sep 16 14:33 gettext.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      43779 Oct 31 03:41 gettextize
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     134940 Oct 31 03:41 gif2h5
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        666 Oct 31 03:43 gifmaker.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     110752 Oct 31 03:42 gio
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      26760 Oct 31 03:42 gio-querymodules
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5269 Oct 31 03:42 glacier
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      67360 Oct 31 03:42 glib-compile-resources
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      72676 Oct 31 03:42 glib-compile-schemas
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      40310 Oct 31 03:42 glib-genmarshal
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5401 Oct 31 03:42 glib-gettextize
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      26561 Oct 31 03:42 glib-mkenums
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      22248 Oct 31 03:42 gobject-query
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      31932 Oct 31 03:42 gresource
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        242 Oct 31 03:42 grin
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        244 Oct 31 03:42 grind
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      45868 Oct 31 03:42 gsettings
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      36724 Oct 31 03:42 gtester
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      18785 Oct 31 03:42 gtester-report
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     133348 Oct 31 03:41 h52gif
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      13404 Oct 31 03:41 h5c++
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      13506 Oct 31 03:41 h5cc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     128356 Oct 31 03:41 h5clear
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     132924 Oct 31 03:41 h5copy
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      24548 Oct 31 03:41 h5debug
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     220840 Oct 31 03:41 h5diff
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     224748 Oct 31 03:41 h5dump
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      12844 Oct 31 03:41 h5fc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     128596 Oct 31 03:41 h5format_convert
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     175048 Oct 31 03:41 h5import
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     129076 Oct 31 03:41 h5jam
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     161248 Oct 31 03:41 h5ls
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     128584 Oct 31 03:41 h5mkgrp
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     160480 Oct 31 03:41 h5perf_serial
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       5913 Sep 22 16:06 h5redeploy
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     203876 Oct 31 03:41 h5repack
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      18508 Oct 31 03:41 h5repart
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     145964 Oct 31 03:41 h5stat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     128900 Oct 31 03:41 h5unjam
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     137684 Oct 31 03:41 h5watch
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      33340 Sep 12 16:42 iconv
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      23167 Oct 31 03:41 icu-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      17712 Oct 31 03:41 icuinfo
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        116 Oct 31 03:41 idle
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      64208 Sep 11 20:39 infocmp
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          3 Oct 31 03:41 infotocap -> tic
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       5801 Oct 31 03:42 instance_events
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        405 Oct 31 03:43 iptest
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        407 Oct 31 03:43 iptest2
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        253 Oct 31 03:43 ipython
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        253 Oct 31 03:43 ipython2
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        238 Oct 31 03:43 isort
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      37504 Sep 15 00:06 isql
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      11731 Oct 31 03:43 isympy
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      28072 Sep 15 00:06 iusql
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      36940 Sep 13 17:16 jpegtran
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        422 Oct 31 03:43 jsonschema
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        237 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-bundlerextension
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        247 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-console
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        290 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter-kernelspec
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        256 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-lab
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        263 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-labextension
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        444 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-labhub
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter-migrate
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        250 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter-nbconvert
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-nbextension
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-notebook
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        123 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-qtconsole
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter-run
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        253 Oct 31 03:44 jupyter-serverextension
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        253 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter-troubleshoot
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        281 Oct 31 03:43 jupyter-trust
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff         41 Sep 22 23:21 jupyter_mac.command
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        947 Oct 31 03:42 kill_instance
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      10628 Oct 31 03:42 launch_instance
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     246044 Oct 31 03:42 lconvert
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       1182 Feb 16  2017 less-watch
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff         15 Oct 31 03:41 libpng-config -> libpng16-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2339 Oct 31 03:41 libpng16-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       3121 Oct 31 03:42 list_instances
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     466816 Oct 31 03:42 lrelease
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       3467 Oct 31 03:42 lss3
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     849860 Oct 31 03:42 lupdate
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          2 Oct 31 03:41 lzcat -> xz
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzcmp -> xzdiff
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzdiff -> xzdiff
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzegrep -> xzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzfgrep -> xzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzgrep -> xzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzless -> xzless
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          2 Oct 31 03:41 lzma -> xz
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      13972 Sep 11 20:42 lzmadec
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      13724 Sep 11 20:42 lzmainfo
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 lzmore -> xzmore
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      76372 Oct 31 03:42 macchangeqt
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     198484 Oct 31 03:42 macdeployqt
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      63376 Oct 31 03:41 makeconv
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     866140 Oct 31 03:42 moc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      28380 Oct 31 03:41 msgattrib
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      28488 Oct 31 03:41 msgcat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      33412 Oct 31 03:41 msgcmp
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      28484 Oct 31 03:41 msgcomm
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      28028 Oct 31 03:41 msgconv
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      28036 Oct 31 03:41 msgen
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      23516 Oct 31 03:41 msgexec
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      33716 Oct 31 03:41 msgfilter
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      87992 Oct 31 03:41 msgfmt
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     120272 Oct 31 03:41 msggrep
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      53024 Oct 31 03:41 msginit
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      58788 Oct 31 03:41 msgmerge
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      42728 Oct 31 03:41 msgunfmt
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      28300 Oct 31 03:41 msguniq
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      19171 Oct 31 03:42 mturk
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        265 Oct 31 03:43 navigator-updater
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       6117 Oct 31 03:42 ncursesw6-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      38516 Oct 31 03:41 ngettext
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        240 Oct 31 03:43 nosetests
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        155 Oct 31 03:43 numba
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      12828 Oct 31 03:41 odbc_config
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      28956 Sep 15 00:06 odbcinst
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        792 Oct 31 03:43 odo
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     573112 Sep 20 09:10 openssl
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2178 Oct 31 03:43 painter.py
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      18224 Sep 13 17:17 pal2rgb
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff  117023956 Sep 11 22:01 pandoc
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff  110312276 Sep 11 22:01 pandoc-citeproc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2383 Oct 31 03:42 pcre-config
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      42512 Sep 12 23:15 pcregrep
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      75656 Sep 12 23:15 pcretest
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        234 Oct 31 03:42 pep8
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2383 Oct 31 03:43 pilconvert.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      15535 Oct 31 03:43 pildriver.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2691 Oct 31 03:43 pilfile.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1052 Oct 31 03:43 pilfont.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2622 Oct 31 03:43 pilprint.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        231 Oct 31 03:43 pip
drwxr-xr-x    3 me  staff        102 Oct 31 03:42 pixeltool.app
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      45876 Oct 31 03:41 pkgdata
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        247 Oct 31 03:42 pkginfo
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2109 Oct 31 03:43 player.py
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      12764 Sep 12 17:02 png-fix-itxt
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      53248 Sep 12 17:02 pngfix
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      18324 Sep 13 17:18 ppm2tiff
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:43 pt2to3
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:43 ptdump
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        251 Oct 31 03:43 ptrepack
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:43 pttree
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        235 Oct 31 03:43 py.test
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2640 Oct 31 03:42 pyami_sendmail
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        251 Oct 31 03:42 pybabel
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        141 Oct 31 03:43 pycc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        241 Oct 31 03:42 pycodestyle
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        101 Oct 31 03:41 pydoc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        412 Oct 31 03:43 pyflakes
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        244 Oct 31 03:43 pygmentize
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        246 Oct 31 03:43 pylint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        254 Oct 31 03:43 pylint-gui
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     198000 Oct 31 03:43 pylupdate5
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      65768 Oct 31 03:43 pyrcc5
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        252 Oct 31 03:43 pyreverse
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        235 Oct 31 03:43 pytest
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          9 Oct 31 03:41 python -> python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff         16 Oct 31 03:41 python-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        147 Oct 31 03:42 python.app
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          9 Oct 31 03:41 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff         16 Oct 31 03:41 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      12560 Oct 31 03:41 python2.7
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1704 Oct 31 03:41 python2.7-config
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        147 Oct 31 03:42 pythonw
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff         55 Sep 21 19:49 pyuic5
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      69088 Oct 31 03:42 qcollectiongenerator
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff    1382504 Oct 31 03:42 qdoc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     168300 Oct 31 03:42 qhelpconverter
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      35836 Oct 31 03:42 qhelpgenerator
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     124824 Oct 31 03:42 qlalr
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff    4513784 Oct 31 03:42 qmake
drwxr-xr-x    3 me  staff        102 Oct 31 03:42 qml.app
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     110096 Oct 31 03:42 qmleasing
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     225268 Oct 31 03:42 qmlimportscanner
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     162404 Oct 31 03:42 qmllint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     108044 Oct 31 03:42 qmlmin
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     160900 Oct 31 03:42 qmlplugindump
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     179228 Oct 31 03:42 qmlprofiler
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      64644 Oct 31 03:42 qmlscene
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      24872 Oct 31 03:42 qmltestrunner
-rw-rw-r--    1 me  staff        193 Oct 31 03:42 qt.conf
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      69600 Oct 31 03:42 qtdiag
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      34348 Oct 31 03:42 qtpaths
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      32460 Oct 31 03:42 qtplugininfo
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      26608 Sep 13 17:17 raw2tiff
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     766788 Oct 31 03:42 rcc
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      13424 Sep 13 17:16 rdjpgcom
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      22520 Oct 31 03:41 recode-sr-latin
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          4 Oct 31 03:41 reset -> tset
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       9057 Oct 31 03:42 route53
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        619 Oct 31 03:42 rst2html.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        739 Oct 31 03:42 rst2html4.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1164 Oct 31 03:42 rst2html5.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        816 Oct 31 03:42 rst2latex.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        625 Oct 31 03:42 rst2man.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        789 Oct 31 03:42 rst2odt.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1723 Oct 31 03:42 rst2odt_prepstyles.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        626 Oct 31 03:42 rst2pseudoxml.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        662 Oct 31 03:42 rst2s5.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        896 Oct 31 03:42 rst2xetex.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        627 Oct 31 03:42 rst2xml.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        695 Oct 31 03:42 rstpep2html.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      16278 Oct 31 03:42 runxlrd.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      16862 Oct 31 03:42 s3put
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        263 Oct 31 03:43 samp_hub
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       7018 Oct 31 03:42 sdbadmin
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     329588 Sep 13 17:35 sip
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        249 Oct 31 03:44 skivi
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      13440 Sep 15 00:06 slencheck
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      18564 Oct 31 03:41 smtpd.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        416 Oct 31 03:44 sphinx-apidoc
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        418 Oct 31 03:44 sphinx-autogen
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        414 Oct 31 03:44 sphinx-build
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        424 Oct 31 03:44 sphinx-quickstart
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        255 Oct 31 03:44 spyder
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff    1341572 Sep 11 20:47 sqlite3
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      29841 Sep 11 20:44 sqlite3_analyzer
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 symilar
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      47182 Sep 21 18:59 syncqt.pl
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      18096 Sep 11 20:39 tabs
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       3792 Oct 31 03:42 taskadmin
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          8 Oct 31 03:41 tclsh -> tclsh8.6
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      12824 Sep 11 20:44 tclsh8.6
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2006 Oct 31 03:43 thresholder.py
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      78192 Sep 11 20:39 tic
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      22448 Sep 13 17:17 tiff2bw
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      86060 Sep 13 17:17 tiff2pdf
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      55276 Sep 13 17:17 tiff2ps
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      22832 Sep 13 17:17 tiff2rgba
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      26488 Sep 13 17:17 tiffcmp
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      46160 Sep 13 17:18 tiffcp
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff     108592 Sep 13 17:17 tiffcrop
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      22424 Sep 13 17:17 tiffdither
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      23520 Sep 13 17:17 tiffdump
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      23876 Sep 13 17:17 tiffinfo
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      27124 Sep 13 17:17 tiffmedian
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      18164 Sep 13 17:18 tiffset
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      18448 Sep 13 17:18 tiffsplit
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      19700 Sep 11 20:39 toe
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      19308 Sep 11 20:39 tput
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      24192 Sep 11 20:39 tset
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     419400 Oct 31 03:42 uic
-rwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff        242 Nov  1 23:57 unidecode
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          2 Oct 31 03:41 unlzma -> xz
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          2 Oct 31 03:41 unxz -> xz
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1978 Oct 31 03:42 vba_extract.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       1045 Oct 31 03:43 viewer.py
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        253 Oct 31 03:43 volint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        247 Oct 31 03:43 wcslint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        238 Oct 31 03:43 wheel
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          7 Oct 31 03:41 wish -> wish8.6
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      21280 Sep 11 20:44 wish8.6
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      13480 Sep 13 17:16 wrjpgcom
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff     308236 Oct 31 03:41 xgettext
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff        248 Oct 31 03:43 xlwings
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2288 Oct 31 03:42 xml2-config
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      27444 Sep 12 23:37 xmlcatalog
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      74132 Sep 12 23:37 xmllint
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      69440 Oct 31 03:42 xmlpatterns
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      19008 Oct 31 03:42 xmlpatternsvalidator
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      26640 Sep 11 22:21 xmlwf
-rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff       2684 Oct 31 03:42 xslt-config
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      38152 Sep 14 14:51 xsltproc
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      74712 Sep 11 20:42 xz
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          2 Oct 31 03:41 xzcat -> xz
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 xzcmp -> xzdiff
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff      13980 Sep 11 20:42 xzdec
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       6632 Sep 11 20:42 xzdiff
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 xzegrep -> xzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff          6 Oct 31 03:41 xzfgrep -> xzgrep
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       5628 Sep 11 20:42 xzgrep
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       1802 Sep 11 20:42 xzless
-rwxrwxr-x    2 me  staff       2161 Sep 11 20:42 xzmore
-rwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff        238 Nov  2 00:18 youtube-dl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff       5462 Nov  2 00:14 ytdl
```

Comment: What does `which -a conda` say?

Comment: `/Users/me/anaconda2/bin/conda`

Comment: What do you get if you `conda <flag> > /dev/null`?

Comment: nothing...an empty prompt

Comment: you are inside `py35` when you notice it fails, if you go back and activate `py27` do the conda commands work there or still an empty prompt?

Comment: oh yes, it fails in and out any given env...

Comment: You may want to try `sudo script /tmp/foo dtruss /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/python /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/conda` and examine `/tmp/foo` and/or compare similar output for /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/conda (or wherever your working conda is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen in some circumstances if you activate a root environment as a non-root environment, where actual binaries become overwritten with symlinks (possibly pointing back to itself). The symptom you see resembles my issue, and is caused by the executable "conda" actually calling out to a subprocess for an executable "conda_install" for conda install (or similar for the others). For one reason or another, the way of calling the subprocess makes it fail silently if it cannot find the executable.
To verify that you have the same problem, you can run `ls -al /Users/me/anaconda2/bin` and see if any of conda, activate, conda_install, conda_create etc is a dangling symlink or completely missing.

Comment: I run it `ls -al /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/conda` and get:                               `-rwxrwxr-x  1 me  staff  237 Oct 31 03:44 /Users/me/anaconda2/bin/conda`

Comment: Sorry, I meant for you to look at the bin folder for dangling symlinks. I have now edited the answer.

Comment: I have edited the question with the required output. hope that helps!

Comment: is there a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem while install bcolz, anybody helps it, I will be in a great debt then

Answer (score 0):

Something is messed up between pip and conda.
Reinstalling setuptools package has worked for me.

```
pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools
```

After this, conda commands started showing the output on console.